# Regarding extraction of data from multiple cordiantes of multiple nc files and merge to a single raster

Tags: r, loops, r-raster, netcat

I have 365 .nc files for a single year, each containing single day soil moisture information. I want to extract soil moisture information from three different coordinates and write them into three csv files for the given year. Currently, I am able to convert all the 365 .nc files into 365 csv files as given in the attached code. How to proceed further?

```
rm(list = ls())
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
ptf <- "D://SMOS_ECV_SM//SMOS_ECV_SM//ECV_SM_Data_1978_2010//1978"
setwd(ptf) # change your working directory
lf <- list.files(pattern="[.]nc$") # list of files ending in .nc
for(i in lf){
  nc.brick <- brick(i)
  nc.df <- as.data.frame(nc.brick[[1]], xy=T)
  write.csv(nc.df, sub("[.]nc$",".csv",i)) # write to the same file name substituting .nc to .csv
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like the below

```
library(raster)
ptf <- "D://SMOS_ECV_SM//SMOS_ECV_SM//ECV_SM_Data_1978_2010//1978"
ff <- list.files(path=ptf, pattern="[.]nc$", full.names=TRUE)

s <- stack(ff)
points <- rbind(c(0,1), c(100,120), c(80,5))
v <- extract(s, points)

for (i in 1:ncol(v)) {
  write.csv(v[,i,drop=FALSE], paste0("file", i, ".csv"))
}
```

Comment: I got the following error.                                                                                                          Error in if (is.na(get("has_proj_def.dat", envir = .RGDAL_CACHE))) { : 
  argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In .varName(nc, varname, warn = warn) : varname used is: sm
If that is not correct, you can set it to one of: sm, sm_noise, flag, sensor